# layout_gravity not working inside LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got the following code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/new_post_txt_description" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Apparently `android:layout_gravity="top"` does not moves the `TextView` to the up. Anyone knows how to achieve that?

P.S

I saw some ideas about using `RelativeLayout`, but in my case i need both of the controls to be next to each other and use weight attribute as in the example.

Thanks!

Comment: You can put the controls next to each other in relative layout much easier than in Linear layout. Use `layout_toRightOf` attributes. I always have found relative layout to be the most powerful of all.

Comment: Thanks I'll try, but how should I decide how much relative space will every control take in that row?

Comment: Im not sure I understand your question. You dont need to worry about how much space each item takes. Just specify the element id to which you want an element to be at the right/left of.

Comment: Above this LinearLayout i got another layout what also has an EditText and a TextView, i need them aligned, this is something i can achieve with weight.

Comment: You could do all that with relative layout also. Frankly, I stopped using linear layout once I found out all that relative layout can do.

Comment: Check out my answer below, it fixes the prob and you don't have to change everything to relative layouts

Comment: That's good. Perhaps you would like to try relative layouts in future. You might find it hard to go back to linear layouts =)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Changing the textView to this worked for me

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="TEST" />
```

This takes advantage of gravity instead of layout_gravity, but since the textView's height is set to fill_parent it has the same effect

android:gravity sets the gravity of the content of the View its used on.
android:layout_gravity sets the gravity of the View or Layout in its parent.

Comment: Using `android:gravity` worked for me to center a text view in a LinearLayout, but width had to be `match_parent` in my case

Comment: this is a good hack.. but why layout_gravity doesn't work? is there a bug or something?

Answer (score 4):

Set the orientation on your `LinearLayout` to horizontal. i.e.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

The entire purpose of a linear layout is the the subviews come one after the other based on the orientation.  I believe default orientation is vertical.  If you need to add more subview below those 2 then wrap those in another `LinearLayout` with a horizontal orientation.

Answer (score 0):

**layout_gravity** doesn't work if you don't add `android:orientation="vertical"` in the Linear Layout.

For example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- Your Code Here -->   

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'm not convinced this  is true, as I did an experiment to see, if setting the orientation on a linear layout would allow a child view to have a android:layout_gravity="right". It did not work, the child view stayed aligned left, even though the child view having gravity applied had a height and width of wrap content.